# Create walls in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision

So I'm creating a game in XNA using C#, and I have walls that are created in random positions, and I'm trying to stop things walking through them/be teleported to points on the screen when they hit them. (Note, Left and right now works, it's just the top and bottom)

```
if (collision(wallRect[k], wallColours, pacmanRect, pacmanColor, 0))
//Collision works, not an issue here
{
    if (pacmanRect.Bottom > wallRect[k].Top && pacmanRect.Top < wallRect[k].Bottom)
    {
        if (pacmanRect.Right >= wallRect[k].Left  
            && pacmanRect.Right < wallRect[k].Right)
        {
            pacmanPos.X = wallRect[k].X - frameSize.X; 
            //frameSize is the size of the pacman sprite
        }                                
        else if (pacmanRect.Left <= wallRect[k].Right 
                  && pacmanRect.Left > wallRect[k].Left)
        {
            pacmanPos.X = wallRect[k].X + frameSize.X / 8;
        }
    }
    else if (pacmanRect.Right > wallRect[k].Left && pacmanRect.Left < wallRect[k].Right)
    {
        if (pacmanRect.Bottom >= wallRect[k].Top)
        {
            pacmanPos.Y = wallRect[k].Y - frameSize.Y / 8;
        }                  
        else if (pacmanRect.Top <= wallRect[k].Bottom)
        {
             pacmanPos.Y = wallRect[k].Y + frameSize.Y / 8;
        }
   }
   playSound(collisionSoundInstance);
}
```

That is the last point in the game loop where pacmanPos is updated. So how would I make it so that the walls are actual walls, and you can't walk through them?

Comment: I don't understand what the question. Do you have a question? Is the code not working? If it's not working, what are you expecting it to do that it's not doing? Can you use a debugger to walk through the code?

Comment: Hope that helped clear it up. It's just not doing what I expect, or what I want.

Comment: If you want to stay to your own code you should explain how it is working, what is frameSize? What does the collision method?

Comment: So what do you expect or want it to do? And please be very specific. Wanting it to "stop things walking through walls" is not specific enough.

Comment: Well I'm intending to use a method so that if a collision is detected on a certain edge of the square, the sprite is moved so that it is in line with the square, i.e if it's on the left, it's moved to wallrect[k].X - frameSize.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (pacmanRect.Bottom > wallRect[k].Top && pacmanRect.Top < wallRect[k].Bottom)
```

Does this make sense? I don't think it's possible for Pacman to be above the top of the wall, but simultaneously below the bottom of it (unless maybe your y-coordinate system is positive in the down direction, and even then the logic still looks fishy)

I would recommend drawing one of the states out on paper, then going through your code in your mind line-by-line given what you see on your paper. For example, draw the state of Pacman's bottom-most edge overlapping the wall's top-most edge. Then walk through your code and see what happens.

Comment: The standard XNA coordinate system is Y increases down, and X increases right. 
This is right, because it's saying that the bottom of pacman needs to be below the top of the wall, and the top of pacman needs to be above the bottom of the wall. 

It's basically providing information if the pacman sprite is on either the left or on the right of the wall sprite.

However, it does work better with OR, as there appears to be less 'slipping', so if you're near one of the corners pacman doesn't jump as much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a game which is restricted to two dimensions you should use [Box2D](http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/) which makes your life much easier.

*See comment if you want to stay to your own code*

Comment: Comment: I know that the answer isn't answering the question but i think he could solve this problem this way.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend / use Box2D unless I had some good physics requirements that I didn't want to write myself. Using something like Box2D will provide some application and learning overhead which can be greater than writing your basic collision detection yourself, depending on your game requirements of course.

Comment: Well it's for a university assignment, and I'm not allowed to use an external engine, so it's not helpful for me, but others may find it useful.